# What difference will it make if I do kmeans twice?

Tags: r, k-means

What difference will it make in my output if I do kmeans once or twice. I'm getting slight different output but between_SS / total_SS is same. I  thought I should get exactly same output.

```
km.res <- kmeans(data, centers = k, nstart = 10)
```

or

```
km.res <- kmeans(data, centers = k, nstart = 10)
km.res <- kmeans(data, centers = k, nstart = 10)
```

Comment: `kmeans` is a stocatic process that uses a bit of randomness to work so each time you run it you can get a different result. If you want to get the same results, you can set the random number generator seed before you call the function with `set.seed(10)` (or whatever number you want), but that will affect all random numbers generated after that point.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26364/variability-in-k-means-clusters-results-setting-set-seed-before/26365